# Gensim - Timeslice Data Format?

Tags: python, python-2.7, gensim

I'd like to use gensim's Python wrapper for Dynamic Topic Models. Essentially, it is a topic modeling approach that slices the corpus by date (i.e. years) and looks at how topics evolve over time. However, I am finding nothing online that specifies how [my_timeslices](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/dtmmodel.html#gensim.models.dtmmodel.DtmModel.ftimeslices) should be formatted. Does anyone have an example of a file and/or preparation?

Comment: With a cursory search online I can't seem to find anything helpful either, but in the wrapper source file on the gensim [github](https://github.com/piskvorky/gensim/blob/develop/gensim/models/wrappers/dtmmodel.py) I found an email address for Artyom Topchyan <artyom.topchyan@live.com> in the license, who I believe wrote the original wrapper file. It might be worth the time to just send Artyom an email.

Comment: Thanks, I started with the google group, will post the answer if I get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I just noticed this. The time_slices is basically a list of integers. Every integer outlines how many of the documents are in each time slice.

Artyom